# Pickle Queue objects in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I have a class that uses a list of Queue objects. I need to pickle this class including the information saved in the queue objects. For example:

```
import Queue
import pickle

class QueueTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.queueList = []
    def addQueue(self):
        q = Queue.Queue()
        q.put('test')
        self.queueList.append(q)


obj = QueueTest()
obj.addQueue()

with open('pickelTest.dat','w') as outf:
    pickle.dump(obj,outf)
```

returns the error

```
raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle lock objects
```

Is there a work around to pickle Queue objects?

Comment: Do you need the synchronization features of `Queue.Queue`? That is, are you using your queues to communicate between various threads, or just as a regular data structure?

Comment: just a regular data structure

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest replacing your uses of `Queue.Queue` with `collections.deque`. The `Queue` class is intended to be used for synchronized communication between threads, so it will have some unnecessary overhead when used as a regular data structure. `collections.deque` is a faster alternative. (The name "deque" is pronounced "deck" and means "double-ended queue".)

The `deque` class does have a different API than the `Queue` type, but it should be pretty easy to translate between them. Use `deque.append` in place of `Queue.put` and `deque.popleft` in place of `q.get()` (or `appendleft` and `pop`, if you feel like going the other direction). Rather than calling `Queue.empty`, just use a `deque` instance as a Boolean value (like you do to test for an empty list).

`deque` instances are picklable:

```
>>> import collections, pickle
>>> q = collections.deque(["test"])
>>> pickle.dumps(q)
b'\x80\x03ccollections\ndeque\nq\x00]q\x01X\x04\x00\x00\x00testq\x02a\x85q\x03Rq\x04.'
```

Answer (score 4):

As you have commented to @Blckknght, you don't need the synchronization features of `Queue.Queue`. So just use `collections.deque` that the `Queue.Queue` class uses itself as the underlying queue data structure. You will have to use `.appendleft` to emulate the FIFO `Queue.put` and `.pop` to emulate `Queue.get`