# Python: how to use pickle to dump Queue objects?

Tags: python, multithreading, serialization, locking, queue

The problem is that directly using pickle to dump Queue will raise an Exception. I have read this similar post but not got my answer yet:
[Pickle Queue objects in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754116/pickle-queue-objects-in-python)

I really can't replace Queue with collections.deque because I'm running a multithreading program, in which Queue is used for synchronization.

So how can I do this?

Comment: I guess there would be some strategies to pickle the Queue, but what for? If you want to use it as a safepoint to restore it later, there are many questions to be answered. The most interesting would be how to get the right item for pickling while the might change and even better: how to restore them in a thread-safe way. I tried that in a recent project, it became a RaceConditionFactory and I had to find a completely different solution.

Comment: @KlausD. My task is more specific. After the master thread terminates other threads for some reason(either by an exception or Ctrl-C), I want it to save Queue to disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to save the queue remaining content from *the* (one and only one) master thread after all consumer and producer threads have terminated, you just have to dump your queue to a plain of list -- and use pickle to persist that list.

```
def qdumper(q):
    try:
        yield q.get(False)
    except queue.Empty:
        pass

remaining = [item for item in qdumper(my_queue)]
pickle.dump(remaining, ....)
```