# Is there a way to pickle a PriorityQueue?

Tags: python-3.x

This is Python 3.10. I use a `PriorityQueue` as a way to track Actors' turn order in my game. It's just a simple roguelike. I don't use the synchronization features of the `PriorityQueue`. My code:

```
import pickle
from queue import PriorityQueue

class GameEngine():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pqueue = PriorityQueue()

    def save_to_file(self):
        with open('save.pkl', 'wb') as file:
            pickle.dump(self, file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

class Monster():
    pass

engine = GameEngine()
orc1 = Monster()
orc2 = Monster()

engine.pqueue.put((20,orc1))
engine.pqueue.put((10,orc2))

engine.save_to_file()
```

It returns `TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object`. From what I understand PriorityQueue is not pickle-able. I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754116/pickle-queue-objects-in-python) that `Queue.Queue` has a pickle-able alternative of `collections.deque` if the synchronization stuff is not necessary. Is there such an alternative to `PriorityQueue`, or is there a way to pickle it anyway? Other than implementing my own simplified version of `PriorityQueue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't need the synchronisation features of PriorityQueue, just use the light-weight `heapq` module. It provides functions (not methods) to work on a plain list:

```
import pickle
from heapq import heappush, heappop

class GameEngine():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pqueue = []

    def save_to_file(self):
        with open('save.pkl', 'wb') as file:
            pickle.dump(self, file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

class Monster():
    pass

engine = GameEngine()
orc1 = Monster()
orc2 = Monster()

heappush(engine.pqueue, (20,orc1))
heappush(engine.pqueue, (10,orc2))

engine.save_to_file()
```